# ASP.NET Screen capture

Tags: asp.net, screen, capture

I am developing ASP.NET apps (using latest 4.0). I always wondering if there is a way to capture the screen of the users and save it to a folder for error logging purposes?
Can I install a Win-form on each users machine and execute it when ASP.NET pages run into error.
Please advise.
Thanks

Comment: You should be logging the error in your application code, and not trying to capture a user's screen.

Answer (score 1):

It is theoretically possible to install a browser plugin that will trigger a screen capture when an error occurs. The first problem though is that you would need that screen capture from before the error - either some very clever error handling or a time machine.

But this will anyway require you to install software on your users machines thus taking away any benefit you get from a web based application. For example, you will have to handle all possible OS/browser combinations.

The only reasonable way of getting that screenshot is showing a custom error message that asks the user to provide the screen shot themselves manually.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that the screen capture would need to be from BEFORE the error.